# Why does the piano sound of my keyboard sound so "odd" through my audio interface?

Tags: daw, piano, interface

I use a Yamaha psr-s670 and a focusrite 2i2 interface for production. When I choose a sound like Strings or Sax, the audio sounds clean and rich in the DAW, but when it comes to the Grand Piano it sounds just like one of those Free Piano VSTs. How can I fix this?

Comment: There are some free piano VSTs that sound great, so this tells us nothing. If you're serious about getting help with something, describe in detail how you're connecting everything and post an audio clip that demonstrates the problem. Otherwise, I suggest the question be closed as too vague.

Comment: When does the psr Grand sound clean and rich? What is special about that chain? How does it differ from your focusrite chain? As it stands, your question is impossible to answer